# When applying a function to a dataframe, is it better to have each column as an argument or the whole row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

For example, when you want to apply a function `calc_val()` to a dataframe, and you have the freedom to define the function, is it better to give it a signature like `def calc_val(a, b, c)` or `def calc_val(row)` or def calc_val(df)? In other words, option A, B or C:

**Option A** has the advantage of showing which columns are being handled by the function, but the `lambda` is also messy and makes readability worse by burying the important info (i.e. the function call to `calc_val_a`) farther along the line, which sometimes makes it harder to see where the function is being used when scanning through the code.

**Option B** is cleaner and more concise, but still sort of buries the function being called and also doesn't show which columns are involved in the calculation.

**Option C** is very clear on what function is being applied by burying the `apply` along the rows, unlike options A and B, but it doesn't show that a new column was added to the dataframe nor which columns were used in that calculation.

Assuming these function calls were to appear in the `main()` function of some data-wrangling script, is there a standard or accepted best practice for readability of something like this?

(Side note: I'm also aware that `apply` is not ideal for speed, but I am mainly focused on readability while processing relatively small datasets. However, if anyone has advice for replacing `apply` calls for functions operating on multiple dataframe columns, that would be helpful in this context as well.)

## Option A:

```
def calc_val_a(a, b, c):
    if c==1:
        val = a*b
    elif c=='2:
        val = a-b
    return val

df['val'] = df.apply(lambda row: calc_val_a(row.a, row.b, row.c), axis=1)
```

## Option B:

```
def calc_val_b(row):
    a = row.a
    b = row.b
    c = row.c
    if c==1:
        val = a*b
    elif c=='2:
        val = a-b
    return val

df['val'] = df.apply(calc_val_b, axis=1)
```

## Option C:

```
def calc_val_c(df):
    df['val'] = df.apply(calc_val_b, axis=1)
    return df

df = calc_val(df)
```

Comment: Once `Option C` is re-written to use `np.select` it will be the desired best option IMO

Comment: My reaction to `apply` is generally *no, you should think of a way around applying a function to every columns*.

Comment: @QuangHoang, true, there is the possibility of using `df['val'] = [calc_val_a(x, y, z) for x, y, z in zip(df.x, df.y, df.z)]`, but this seems very repetitive, despite some performance gains. Any other options?

Comment: As commented by @ALollz `df['val'] = np.select( (df['c']==1, df['c']==2), (df[a]*df[b], df[a]-df[b]), default=df['c'])`.

Comment: Assuming that the function is any level of complexity though, I'm looking more generally at what format to use for the signature